# Handle redis cache availability with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have below Cache Repo with other methods,

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "enroll", cacheManager = "springtoolCM")
public class EnrollCasheRepository {

    /** The string redis template. */
    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

}
```

I am using spring-boot-starter-redis in the pom.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**I am using `EnrollCasheRepository` in my filter with `@Autowired`.**

Even I comment out redis properties in `application.properties`and also my redis server is down, but I still get an `EnrollCasheRepository` object. What would be a better way to check whether redis is install in my machine and proceed with `EnrollCasheRepository` if so.

I am looking for a better way other than handle Exception thrown if redis not installed and proceed?

Comment: did you check your local services that Redis server is up or not?

Comment: Even redis server is down, I still get a EnrollCasheRepository object populate with default values

Comment: Which version of spring-boot you are using?

Comment: @rajadilipkolli 1.3.4

Comment: So you want to not register a `EnrollCasheRepository` when you omit the redis properties or redis is down, am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring-boot redis configuration is provided by [`RedisAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.java)
This class creates the connection factory and initializes the `StringRedisTemplate` bean.

The configuration is dependant on having Jedis available on the classpath.
It appears that there is no test to check if the connection details are valid or not.

If you want to have your `EnrollCasheRepository` bean created dependant on jedis being configured, the simplest way to achieve it is probably going to be annotating it with [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) and creating a feature flag config value.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("redis.enabled")
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "enroll", cacheManager = "springtoolCM")
public class EnrollCasheRepository {
```

Add the flag to your application.properties(or equivalent)

```
redis.enabled=true
```

If you want to be more intelligent about it, like detecting if the configured redis server is available before creating the bean, then that would be more complex.
You could look at using [`@Conditional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html?is-external=true) with your own implementation of [`Condition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html), but that is probably more trouble than it is worth.
You are probably better off creating the bean, then testing if it works after the fact.

Comment: `Condition` is an *interface*, hence there is no need for the `@` sign. Anyway +1 for your great answer

Comment: Even I add redis.enabled=true with other redis configuration, still I get null for EnrollCasheRepository in my Filter

Comment: Hard to say, are you sure that your filter is being initialized by spring, if you back-out the conditional annotation does it get autowired?

Comment: Actually my filter get hit twice in an invocation. So in first hit  EnrollCasheRepository is null but in second hit its autowired. Its something to do with Filter registration with Spring boot which I have to look seperate.

Comment: Also I notice, need to add required=false when Autowired.   @Autowired(required=false)